# doWork() method is never called after enqueue

Tags: android, android-workmanager

doWork() method is never called after enqueue, Relavent code from MainActivity from which I am trying to enqueue

```
val constraints = Constraints.Builder()
            .setRequiresBatteryNotLow(true)
            .build()
    val measurementSyncWork = OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(MeasurementSyncWork::class.java).setConstraints(constraints).addTag(MeasurementSyncWork.TAG).build()
    var operation = WorkManager.getInstance()?.enqueue(measurementSyncWork)
```

Code inside Work class

```
class MeasurementSyncWork(context: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters) : Worker(context, workerParams) {

companion object {
    const val TAG = "MeasurementSyncWork"
}

override fun doWork(): Result {
    return try {
        Result.success()
    } catch (throwable: Throwable) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error while downloading measurements", throwable)
        Result.failure()
    }

}
```

}

Libraries used

```
ext.android_support_version = '28.0.0'
ext.android_multidex_version = '1.0.3'
ext.androidx_work = '1.0.0-alpha12'
ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.71'
ext.lifecycle_version = '1.1.1'
ext.retrofit_version = '2.4.0'
ext.dagger2_version = '2.16'
ext.room_version = '1.1.1'
ext.gradle_version = '3.1.0'
ext.moshi_version = "1.8.0"
ext.caroutines_version = "0.26.1"
ext.junit_version = "4.12"
ext.stetho_version = "1.5.0"
ext.rx_java_version = "2.2.0"
ext.rx_android_version = "2.1.0"
```

Comment: It was a issue with manifest merge,  I removed this "tools:node="replace" flag from AndroidManifest and it started working. For more information follow this reply from Google at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/123005661